# React routes not working with embedded Spring boot project

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, react-router

I am developing an application which has React frontend and Springboot backend. React app is inside the SpringBoot app and deployed with it. I have added spring security to the app and primary focus is to add a custom login page and display simple landing page when login success (it uses the maven-frontend plugin). Though I have configured routes and security configs, it is not working properly.

Here is my security config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/dashboard").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("employee");
    }
}
```

And here is my React app routing,

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8090"
}
```

When I started the react app separately and launch url (localhost:3000/login and /dashboard) it works. But with Springboot app when I launch localhost:8090/login it gives **WhiteLabel Error as 404**

PS: There are two other modules to the whole spring app and one is running a server on 8080 and other module is a model collection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, your spring boot build is happening properly, where it copies the  react build package onto resource (`/static`) directory. And also, this may require web-security policy update to allow all static resources. Which are required by react application to bootstrap itself. like allowing (*.js and *.css) extensions.

If you're getting `WhiteLabel Error` page means the react application even not loaded yet. Still routing could be with spring servlet layer.